# Add new button Ribbon "Page" SP 2013 Ent

Tags: javascript, css, master-page, custom-masterpage, html

Tell me how to add a button to the Ribbon panel, without using a separate project in Visual Studio, that is possible?

[image]

Comment: Depends on what kind of action you need. SPD might be enough. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh500259(v%3Doffice.14)#creating-a-custom-action-by-using-sharepoint-designer

Comment: @Christoffer thank Items is working fine, but how is add button in Wiki Page? Main panel Ribbon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only VS, this simple example is helped me:

1. Open the visual studio 2012 as run as administrator.
2. Create an Empty SharePoint Project.
3. [image]
4. Select a Farm Solution.
5. [image]
6. Add New Item to the solution.
7. [image]
8. Add a Module. Name it as CustomRibbonActionModule.
9. By default, it will have a sample.txt. Now delete that txt file, since we don’t require that.
10. And modify the Elements.xml as below.
11. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction Description="Open template"
             Id="68275191-272b-4c59-a9ee-ee736f76f2e5"
             Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
             Title="Open template">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Clipboard.Controls._children">
          <Button
              Id="Open template"
              Alt="Open template"
              Sequence="100"
              Command="CustomRibbonButton_CopyHtml_Command"
              Image16by16="/_layouts/images/NoteBoard_16x16.png"
              Image32by32="/_layouts/images/NoteBoard_32x32.png"
              LabelText="Open template"
              TemplateAlias="o1" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler
          Command="CustomRibbonButton_CopyHtml_Command"
     CommandAction="javascript:openDialog('/SitePages/Template.aspx');" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
    </CustomAction>
    <CustomAction
      ScriptSrc="scripts/script.js"
      Location="ScriptLink"
      Sequence="100">
    </CustomAction>
    <Module Name="CustomRibbonActionModule">
    </Module>
    </Elements>`